# Why "foreach" don't echo?

Tags: php, foreach

Learn php

```
<?php
     $a = 3;
     if ($a>1){
        $arr = array (1,2,3);
     }
     foreach ($arr as $b) {
        echo $b[0];
        echo $b[1];
        echo $b[2];
     }
     var_dump($arr);
      ?>
```

I don't know why it can not echo in foreach?
But `var_dump($arr)` still run with result:

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) }
```

But when I wrote: $arr[] it can run.

```
<?php
 $a = 3;
 if ($a>1){
    $arr[]= array (1,2,3);
 }
 foreach ($arr as $b) {
    echo $b[0];
    echo $b[1];
    echo $b[2];
 }
 var_dump($arr); 
  ?>
```

Result:

```
123
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) } }
```

Both of them are same result with var_dump. So what different between `$arr` and `$arr[]` ?

Comment: Because `foreach` iterates over array, and `$b` is a currently iterated value, ie 1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: A multi - dimensional array $arr = [ [1,2,3], [3,4,5], [6,7,8] ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines:

```
$arr = array (1,2,3);
```

and

```
$arr[]= array (1,2,3);
```

are not equivalent. Look more closely at the two `var_dump` outputs, and you'll see the difference.

In the former, you're creating a one dimensional array - when you try to loop over it, you'll get an iteration with `$b` set to each of the three values (**1**, **2** and **3**) in turn. Each time, `$b` is an integer. Any "index" of it will return null, since you can't deference scalar values (other than strings). This is [defined in the manual here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> Array dereferencing a scalar value which is not a string silently yields NULL, i.e. without issuing an error message.

And when you echo *null*, nothing happens. It's the equivalent of an empty string, and so no output is produced.

In the second case, you're creating a **two** dimensional array. Writing

```
$arr[]= array (1,2,3);
```

when `$arr` is empty is the same as writing

```
$arr = array(array (1,2,3));
```

This time, when you loop over it, you get a single iteration, with `$b` set to the inner array. Now, echo-ing `$b[0]`, `$b[1]` and `$b[2]` refers to the integers in the array, so you get your expected output of

> 123

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead of you written above:

```
<?php
     $a = 3;
     if ($a>1){
        $arr = array (1,2,3);
     }
     foreach ($arr as $b) {
        echo $b;
        echo '<br>';
     }
     var_dump($arr);
?>
```